# How to retrieve URL lastPathComponent of dropped document while using NSItemProviderReading

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uikit

iOS 11 comes with Drag & Drop. I want to use it in order to import PDF files to my app. I've created a class that conforms to `NSItemProviderReading` protocol by implementing `object(withItemProviderData:typeIdentifier:)` static method and `readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider` property:

```
import Foundation

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
final class MyDropItem: NSObject, NSItemProviderReading {

    @objc let data: Data
    @objc let typeIdentifier: String

    required init(data: Data, typeIdentifier: String) {
        self.data = data
        self.typeIdentifier = typeIdentifier
        super.init()
    }

    static func object(withItemProviderData data: Data, typeIdentifier: String) throws -> Self {
        return self.init(data: data, typeIdentifier: typeIdentifier)
    }

    static var readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String] {
        return [kUTTypePDF as String]
    }

}
```

However, `NSItemProviderReading` does not offer a way to import objects from a their original `URL`. Therefore, I cannot retrieve the `URL` of the original file and keep some relevant parts such as its `lastPathComponent` (e.g. the document name `MyPDFDocument.pdf`).

What should I do in order to be able to create `NSItemProviderReading` conforming objects while getting their related `URL` `lastPathComponent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered that `NSItemProvider` has a property called [`suggestedName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsitemprovider/2890244-suggestedname). `suggestedName` should be used in order to get the name of a dropped item.